Add Role to the Token generated using Client Credentials
We're using Aad Authentication and after authenticating we're having roles and scope present in token. When we generated token for SPN using Client Credentials, this role is missing.
Is there any option that we can get the role and scope information in the token when generating token using Client Id and Client secret ?

Do you want to add AppRole into the JWT token?

Followed this documentation and able to resolve the issue.
